# Issues with promise inside for loop

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to call a promise inside a for loop. I need the call to have the relevant loop item. I read a bit about it but still can't seem to figure the correct way to do it.

```
var params;
var  identifylayers =["parcels", "lots", "gasstation"];
for (i = 0; i < identifylayers.length; i++)
{
        lname = identifylayers[i];

    govmap.intersectFeatures()
    .then(function (e)
    {
       alert( lname);
    });

}
```

Running the function  returns: gasstation,gasstation,gasstation

I want it to return: parcels, lots, gasstation

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how `identifylayers` are being defined?

Comment: its an array of layers that looks like this

Comment: its an array of layers that looks like this [parcels, lots, gasstation]

Comment: its an array of strings basically

Comment: What happens if you `alert( params.layerName);` instead of `alert( lname);`

Comment: the same  gasstation,gasstation,gasstation

Comment: Why to call promise inside the loop , it's better use the promise.all and handle the response inside the then handler. Promise.all([url1,url2]).then([rest,res2]).

Comment: `lname` can only hold one value at a time. By the time the `then` function runs, the loop has already finished long ago and you see the variable's current value three times.

Comment: Start by declaring your `i` and `lname` variables. If you use `let` to declare them, it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the **async** devil of JavaScript lurking in your code. :D

Observe it like this -

1. As soon as your program flow encounter a `promise call` which here is - `intersectFeatures().then(fn (){})`, it know that this call will **eventually** finish so the program flow will never attempt to execute the callback passed to `.then()` right at the moment instead it will keep it safe with itself and set a reminder that as soon as the `intersectFeatures` is finished it need to execute the callback passed to `.then()`.
2. Next thing to notice is how the `.then(callback)` will have access to `lname`. Its by **closures**. So
3. Another important thing to notice is that this whole stuff is inside a loop. Your loop has no idea whether the code its iterating on is synchronous or asynchronous. Its only task is to iterate. And as we mentioned before in *Point - 1* the `.then(callback)` will not be executed right at the moment. **So by the time then `.then(callback)` will be executed your loop would already be finished and at the end of iteration lname holds gasstation. Hence your `.then(callback)` only print gasstation**

**Solution:**

This is really old JS solution of iterating the async code and still ensuring the proper variable access using closures -

```
    for (i = 0; i < identifylayers.length; i++)
    {
        lname = identifylayers[i];
        (function (lname) {
            govmap.intersectFeatures()
                  .then( function () {
                      alert(lname);
                  } )
        })(lname);

    }
```

This utilises the benefit of functional scope of a variable and idea of closures. Google it to find more information.

Its also referred to as **befriending closures**, I just made that up :D

Cheers!

Comment: have heared about closures but never understood it fully .it works .thanks a lot Himanshu .

Comment: Cheers buddy :D Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to know more about closures and practical use case.

Answer (score -1):

Define `lname` in the loop.  Currently it is the same instance for each iteration, so it gets overriden, and then the promise resolves and prints the last overwrite each time.

```
const lname = identifylayers[i];
```

It is getting overriden before the async code runs.

```js
async function intersectFeatures() {
  return "OK"
}

var params;
var identifylayers = ["parcels", "lots", "gasstation"];
for (let i = 0; i < identifylayers.length; i++) {
  const lname = identifylayers[i];
  intersectFeatures()
    .then(function(e) {
      alert(lname);
    });

}
```

Comment: hey steven thatnks for answering but i defined the lname as you suggested but it  didnt solve the problem.

Comment: @LordCorwin I posted a snippet.  It works as expected.  Remove the `const` and it reverts to the behavior you reported.

Comment: use const or let instead of val.  My original solution used the wrong type.

Comment: hey stevan thanks for your time let and async work in chrom browser but some of my users use ie 11 and it doesnt support let or async.

Comment: You don't need to use async.  Returning a promise will do. That was just for testing.  Problem is exactly what I stated.  And IE 11 supports const and let. I updated solution with promise.

Comment: when i use let in  my code in ie 11 i get an undefiend for the i parameter .

Comment: Then declare i as let too.  Will update.